# Using Python to Recognize Fixed Width Text

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, fixed-width

I am provided with a text file that contains many fixed width tables as well as accompanying text that does not belong to any table. Say my file looks something like the following:

> The following is a fixed width table. This paragraph contains some description or summary of the results in the table below.
>
> [Insert Fixed Width Table Here]
>
> This is a second paragraph describing what is in the second fixed width table.
>
> [Insert Second Fixed Width Table Here]
>
> This is a third paragraph describing a third table.
>
> [Third Table Goes Here]
>
> ...

Ideally, I want to parse this text file into something like a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the description of the table as its first element (so a string such as "This is a third paragraph describing a third table."), and a pandas data frame containing the actual table data as the second element.

Now I already know that the pandas package has a read_fwf that can intelligently parse fixed width text into a data frame. However, before I can call read_fwf, I have to separate the contents of the fixed width tables from the rest of the text first. Is there any way that I can easily use python to figure out where my fixed width tables begin and where they end?

The paragraphs of text describing the tables come in many different forms, so I can't "easily" label certain lines as being paragraph lines and not table lines based on what words they contain. Also, there are no extra line breaks in between each table and the beginning of the text describing the next table, so I can't use the existence of an empty line to figure out where a table ends either. Instead, I have to actually look at the contents of the text and see if the text is "fixed width". (I guess I could look for the existence of two or more spaces right next to each other to figure out if a line is possibly fixed width, but that seems like an imperfect solution because plain text could possibly contain two or more subsequent spaces as well).

Comment: So how do your tables look like? It might be simplest to detect text as not being a table, instead of the other way.

Comment: Seems like it could be a promising idea. The column headers for each table should be the same, so I guess we could recognize the start of each table by stripping whitespace from each line and then seeing if it matches the column headers we want. After we do that, it's a question of seeing if subsequent lines "match" the fixed width set by the column header preceding it. I don't really know how to do the second step though.

Comment: You can use `len(line)` to test a lines length. Have a look at `file`/`open` and  how they create *iterators* with `readlines`. It should be easy to create two *generator functions* that work on this iterator, one `yield`ing only table data, the other `yield`ing only non-table data. Identify a header, store its length, then pass on anything that either matches this length or not.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable solution. It could stumble a little if the next paragraph happens to have the exact same number of characters as the fixed width table above, but that will probably be a rare occurrence, if it happens at all.

Comment: Do you your tables have separators? You could count those, or do `str.split` and see how many columns you get. Sorry, without knowing your table format it's difficult to give a robust method.

Comment: My tables usually don't have separators. They're basically just text separated by some number of spaces in order to make it fixed width. I would post an example but I'm not sure how to do linebreaks in a comment.

Comment: Just edit your question. Use the code formatting (indent by 4 spaces).